# ¿Como hacer PING a una dirección IP con PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

Estoy haciendo un sistema de inventario de redes, entre las opciones quiero agregar un botón para hacer `PING` a una determinada dirección `IP`

¿Como lo hago? Estoy utilizando `PHP`, aunque si se puede también lo haría en `Javascript`.

Anexo capture para que entiendan un poco mejor lo que quiero.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este mi archivo **ping.php**:

```
<?php 
include ("db/conexion.php");
$ip=$_REQUEST['ip'];
$comando = $ip;
$output = shell_exec("ping $comando");
echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: ¿Qué sistema operativo usas?

Comment: Estoy utilizando una distribucion derivada de Debian, se llama canaima

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes. Te recomiendo [hacer el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Además te dejo este enlace sobre [Ejecución de programas del sistema con PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/book.exec.php). Intenta hacerlo por tu cuenta primer, sino has podido resolverlo, edita tu pregunta y agrega el código que has realizado

Comment: ¿Dónde quieres que aparezca el resultado del ping? ¿En una página nueva como te he puesto en mi respuesta o en la misma página donde muestras el botón?

Answer (score 9):

A ver... por defecto PING en linux corre para siempre, o sea se mantiene haciendo ping hasta que lo detienes. Por eso existe el flag `c` que te permite limitar la cantidad de peticiones. Por ejemplo haciendo una sola petición:

```
$output = shell_exec("ping -c 1 $ip");
```

**PEEERO** eso es un detalle. Yo cambiaría tu enfoque por tres razones:

1. Ejecutar un comando que se compone de un input de usuario es peligroso. Imagina que el parámetro `ip` es `52.7.164.50 ; cat /etc/passwd`. El output entregaría la salida del ping más el contenido de un archivo sensible.
2. En segundo lugar, dependiendo de la instalación de PHP (configuración, permisos del sistema, etc) puede que simplemente no logres ejecutar comandos.
3. Un ping utiliza el protocolo ICMP. Un host que sirve, por ejemplo, un sitio web, no tiene por qué tener habilitadas las peticiones ICMP. El ping dará timeout. Tú asumirás que el host está caído y en realidad la máquina está encendida pero no responde al ICMP.

Dado lo anterior, yo lo que haría sería utilizar `CURL` enviando una petición de tipo `HEAD`. Es lo que usan servicios como NewRelic o Uptime Robot para comprobar que un sitio web esté arriba.

Además, usaría la función `filter_var` para validar que el input sea una dirección IP válida. El script, que acabo de probar en mi local, quedaría como sigue:

```
<?php
$ip = $_REQUEST['ip'];

if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV4)) {

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ip);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

    // Petición HEAD
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);

    $content = curl_exec($ch);

    if (!curl_errno($ch)) {
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

        print_r("\nSe recibió respuesta " . $info['http_code'] . ' en ' . $info['total_time'] . " segundos \n");
    } else {
        print_r("\nError en petición: " . curl_error($ch) . "\n");
    }

    curl_close($ch);

} else {
    print_r("\nDirección IP no válida: " . $ip . "\n");
}
```

Yo sugeriría hacer esta comprobación usando ajax y hacer que el backend devuelva un json, pero el script de arriba te dejará bastante cerca de lo que quieres lograr.

Answer (score 2):

Luis. He desarrollado la siguiente clase que te servirá para realizar el ping utilizando el protocolo ICMP gracias a la herramientas nativa de los OS; la he diseñado para que sea heterogéneo con OS, por lo que te funcionará en Linux y Windows, donde este detectará en donde se está ejecutando y con respecto a la condicionante reaccionará adecuadamente.

```
<?php

    class CheckDevice {

        public function myOS(){
            if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === (chr(87).chr(73).chr(78)))
                return true;

            return false;
        }

        public function ping($ip_addr){
            if ($this->myOS()){
                if (!exec("ping -n 1 -w 1 ".$ip_addr." 2>NUL > NUL && (echo 0) || (echo 1)"))
                    return true;
            } else {
                if (!exec("ping -q -c1 ".$ip_addr." >/dev/null 2>&1 ; echo $?"))
                    return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }

    $ip_addr = "151.101.193.69"; #DNS: www.stackoverflow.com

    if ((new CheckDevice())->ping($ip_addr))
        echo "The device exists";
    else 
        echo "The device is not connected";
```

Ahí dejo un ejemplo donde intento aplicar una conexión a este sitio, lo puedes hacer mediante la dirección IP o DNS.

Si deseas una mejor explicación del código, por acá he elaborado un pequeño artículo sobre ello: Crashell [Hacer ping desde PHP](https://www.crashell.com/estudio/hacer_ping_desde_php).

Claro está que si el host remoto donde deseas realizar el ping, tienen bloqueado por medio de Firewall el protocolo ICMP, éste no te responderá que está levantado, también se puede hacer realizando un barrido de puertos para comprobar si los más comunes se encuentran abiertos y que puedan responder, de esa manera se podría hacer, éstos si se pueden hacer con Sockets directamente con PHP, pero el chiste es que sea ICMP ya que en una red local puede que en las máquinas no hayan puertos abiertos usuales a cuál hacer las peticiones.

Comment: Esta clase sencilla, es implementada en el software de gestión de red y dispositivos informáticos GNU/Linux, llamado GNet. Acá dejo la referencia: https://github.com/SideMasterGM/GNet/blob/master/app/Desktop/Root/php/class/gn.class.ping.php

Además la implementación de la clase: https://github.com/SideMasterGM/GNet/blob/master/app/Desktop/Root/php/gn.CheckPing.php

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el código de salida de la ejecución de `ping` para saber si el equipo respondió o no y limitar el número de pings realizados (en linux son infinitos por defecto) de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php 
include 'db/conexion.php';
/* Es mejor que la variable exista para enviarla por referencia */
$salida = 0;
/* Ejecutamos un ping con tres intentos y una espera  máxima de 1sg */
$output = system(
  'ping -c 3 -W 1 ' . escapeshellarg($_REQUEST['ip']),
  $salida
);
/* Si el código de salida es 0 el equipo respondió */
if ($salida === 0) {
  echo "PING correcto";
} else {
  echo "PING mal: " + $output;
}
```

Además, hago uso de [`escapeshellarg()`](http://php.net/escapeshellarg) para escapar de manera correcta cualquier carácter que pudiera ser usado para un ataque de inyección de órdenes (tu código es vulnerable).

Como puedes ver en la página del manual de [`system()`](http://php.net/system):

> **Advertencia** Si se va a permitir que datos provenientes del usuario sean enviados a esta función, habría que utilizar `escapeshellarg()` o `escapeshellcmd()` para asegurarse que el usuario no intenta engañar al sistema para que ejecute comandos arbitrarios.

Comment: PD: Estoy a la espera de la respuesta del comentario sobre cómo quiere mostrar esta información en la página para agregar código HTML en caso de nueva ventana, cambio de estilo del botón, modificación de la página actual, etc.

Answer (score 0):

si estás usando Linux podrias intentas hacer una llamada background y recibir la respuesta. algo como esto:

```
$ip = "ip_prueba";
$output = shell_exec("ping $ip");

if (strpos($output, "recibidos = 0")) {
    echo 'No se pudo encontrar el Host..';
} else {
    echo 'Host conectado..';
}
```

Si afinas un poco más las respuestas, creo que esto podría solucionar tu problema. Saludos

Comment: Intento con tu codigo  y no me da ninguna respuesta amigo, la pagina no termina de cargar nunca.

Answer (score 0):

Estoy en un problema similar de inventario, respaldos y actualizaciones de equipos Linux y otros. Como no encontré nada en la web que me servía 100% lo tuve que crear y quiero compartirlo. Esta solución es para un equipo que corre Ubuntu y PHP configurados default.

La idea general es hacer ping y verificar el retorno 0 para OK (el equipo pingeado responde), !=0 no hay respuesta.

Aquí consideramos que el equipo a verificar responde ping, porque está en tu red y bajo tu administración.
Este método demora 1 segundo por cada falla de ping y si tenemos muchos equipos apagados, el tiempo total de analizar un grupo de IPs será largo. Una forma de paralelizar la tarea es usar una imágen de retorno y como el browser pide las imágenes en simultáneo las respuestas se contruyen mientras se muestra el HTML.
Hay que tener dos imágenes para cuando responde ping y cuando no.

Quedaron comentados otras alternativas de respuesta/retorno.

ping.php

```
    <?php
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    $ip=$_REQUEST['ip'];
    if (!preg_match('/^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/', $ip)) { // verifica que sea IP v4 y no otra cosa
        $archivo='noresponde.jpg';
    } else {
        $salida=$ret='';
        exec('ping -c 1 -W 1 ' . $ip,$salida,$ret);
        //return $ret; // 0= responde    1=no responde
        //return ($ret==0); // True= responde    False=no responde
        if ($ret==0) {
            $archivo='responde.jpg';
        } else {
            $archivo='noresponde.jpg';
        }
    }
    echo readfile($archivo);
```

Usar así:

```
echo '<img src="ping.php?ip=' . $ip . '">';
```

Con jQuery también se puede paralelizar y hasta mantener actualizado, pero eso es otro proyecto.
Espero que le sirva.