# Recibir ping en un servidor con PHP

Tags: php, web, macos, ip

estoy intentando hacer ping cada x tiempo desde una placa (no puedo hacer ni GET ni POST), solo PING, y necesito alguna forma de recibir la IP de ese ping con su mac correspondiente, ¿conoceis alguna forma?

Comment: posible duplicado de: `https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/130341/como-hacer-ping-a-una-direcci%C3%B3n-ip-con-php`

Comment: No es exactamente lo que quiero, es decir, mediante wireshark he visto que al hacer un ping, se puede enviar algo de informacion, entonces me gustaria que el servidor pudiese leer la informacion que le envia un cliente y tratarla, igual que hace con un get o un post. Es posible?